# Installing Arial on Ubuntu and using in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, graph, fonts, matplotlib

Ok, I'm trying to install Arial on Ubuntu and then produce a graph using Python, in which I want the text to display in Arial. I'm not sure if the error is with how I have installed Arial, or how I am trying to access it through the Python script, which I've been doing with `pylab.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Arial'`

The above does take effect when I use the name of a preinstalled font instead of Arial. Arial does appear to be installed properly in other ways though; it's showing up in other programs and can be used, it just seems to be in Python that it's not finding it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here is a way of installing Arial on an ubuntu machine : http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/09/installing-microsoft-fonts/ Hope it helps,

Comment: After so many hours, I found we need to install a package in Ubuntu. This package contains the arial font and others. I followed this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097053/matplotlib-cannot-find-basic-fonts.