# Python seaborn plot shows data names as ㅁㅁㅁㅁ. How can I fix this?

Tags: python

I am trying to draw out some graph using Python Seaborn, but it looks like it cannot read the data names. Data is in Korean.

So this happens...

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = ['전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도']

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['province'])
sns.catplot(x='province', kind='count', data=df)
plt.show()
```

Graph

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What would you get with `print(df)`?

Comment: print(df['province'])

0        서울
1        서울
2        서울
3        경기도
           ...
1499  경기도
1500  경기도

Name: province, Length: 1500, dtype: object

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal working example](/help/mcve) so that others can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Yes, I have put the code and the result I get from it.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: [Display foreign language in matplotlib (in virtual env)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374379/display-foreign-language-in-matplotlib-in-virtual-env)

Comment: I'm using Python 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with fonts. Just set your font to something that supports `CJK` (Chinese-Japanese-Korean) characters, e.g. `'Noto Sans CJK JP'`.
Then, just use `sns.set(font=...)` to set it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 

# : setting the font  
sns.set(font='Noto Sans CJK JP') 

a = ['전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '전라북도', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '서울', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도', '경기도'] 

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['province']) 
sns.catplot(x='province', kind='count', data=df)
```

resulting in:

[image]

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753835/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-fonts-currently-available-for-matplotlib) to get a list of the fonts available in your system that Matplotlib (and hence Seaborn) can find.

Comment: It still doesn't work on mine... I'm using PyCharm.

Comment: @Peter It should work with PyCharm too. Do you get any error message? It may be a good idea to run it from a IPython console to see if it works there and/or what error you get.

Comment: Had some trouble downloading and installing different fonts that support Korean and testing them out... but turned out it was as easy as the code below.

sns.set(font='AppleGothic') solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter Cool! Perhaps you may want to upvote / accept this answer then :-)