# Matplotlib LaTeX plots not working: "FileNotFoundError missing font metrics file: rsfs10"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have followed all the steps in the Matplotlib [guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) for using LaTeX fonts in plots and yet I am still getting the error "FileNotFoundError
missing font metrics file: rsfs10" when I try to save my figure. Here are the steps I've taken:

1) I have a 'matplotlibrc' file specifying that one of the supported backends be used

2) I have the MiKTeX 2.9 and Ghostscript 9.26 binary folders in my PATH (my MiKTeX contains dvipng.exe)

3) I have in my script `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)` and `plt.rc('font', family='times')`

Someone was able to solve this on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875637/matplotlib-how-do-i-have-to-provide-font-metrics-files-for-rendering-text-by-te) but I'm unable to follow what exactly they've done.