# Matplotlib does not find basic fonts

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to use Computer Modern (i.e. the standard LaTeX font) in my pyplot figures, however, I get the error

```
findfont: Font family ['serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
```

All I do is:

```
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern']})
```

I have also found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097053/matplotlib-cannot-find-basic-fonts) which dealt with the same issue, however, I cannot install the packages mentioned in the answer there because I am not an admin on the machine I am using. Deleting the matplotlib cache did not help, either. I have located the font, though:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/
```

which has the subfolders afm and ttf (and another one), and within both of them, I find files like

```
cmr10.afm
```

or

```
cmr10.ttf
```

so the fonts are actually installed on the computer. The fontlist-v330.json file links to

```
"fname": "fonts/afm/cmr10.afm"
```

for Computer Modern. I have tried manually changing this to the ttf file, and I have also tried giving it the full path, but to no avail. At this point, I am at a loss for ideas. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do should be using the actual name of the font file:

```
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['cmr10']})
```