# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'font_manager'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I install matplotlib but python 3.8.10 show me this error.

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'font_manager'
```

What i am doing wrong?
[image]

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib')

import matplotlib

system_fonts = matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf') 
print(dir(system_fonts))
```

Answer (score 4):

`font_manager` is a sub-module, and sub-modules aren't imported automatically.  Sometimes the `__init__.py` module will import a sub-module for you, but you can't always count on this.

Import it explicitly:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
```

Comment: Super. Thx. It work. I think before that __init__ always import all sub-modules.